# Base address of HttpClient is getting null for the first time in OnInitializedAsync method in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In my Blazor web app(auto render mode), I have added the http client as service in server project like bellow:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

I also added http client in the web assembly (client) project like bellow:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
```

Now the problem is, when I inject HttpClient in my home page component(in client project), and try to use that service in `OnInitializedAsync` method, it throws an exception first time saying no base address is added, but in the `OnAfterRenderAsync` method the http client works fine with the correct base address.

What should I do to use the HttpClient in `OnInitializedAsync` method?

Comment: Can you show your OnInitializedAsync method?